# How to fix with a few taps?

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine, touch

I have a character rotation, it is based on this. There is a joystick. If you put your finger first on the rotation of the character, and then on the joystick - everything is fine. But if at first on the joystick, and after trying to turn, nothing will happen! Help. A few days can not decide

```
 void Start()
    {
        mContr = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Joystick").GetComponent<MobileController>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(xp > 0)
        {
            deadStatus = false;
            ch_animator.SetBool("dead", false);
        }
        if(xp <= 0)
        {   if(deadStatus == false)
            {
                menu.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                ch_animator.SetBool("Run", false);
                ch_animator.SetBool("Walk", false);
                ch_animator.SetBool("right", false);
                ch_animator.SetBool("left", false);
                ch_animator.SetBool("dead", true);
                dead.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                if(GameObject.Find("selectLvl"))
                {
                    GameObject.Find("selectLvl").SetActive(false);
                }
                if(GameObject.Find("settings"))
                {
                    GameObject.Find("settings").SetActive(false);
                }
                deadStatus = true;
            }
        }
        if(eat > 10)
        {
            if(xp>0&&xp!=100) {
                xp += Time.deltaTime * 1f;
                eat -= Time.deltaTime * 0.5f;
            }
            speedMove = 3;
        } else {
            speedMove = 1;
            if(eat < 1 ) {
                xp -= Time.deltaTime * 0.06f;
            }
        }
        if(xp.ToString() != hpText.text) {
            hpText.text = Math.Round(xp).ToString();
        }
        if(eat.ToString() != eatText.text)
        {
            eatText.text = Math.Round(eat).ToString();
        }
        if(star.ToString() != starText.text)
        {
            starText.text = star.ToString();
        }
        if(gun.ToString() != gunText.text)
        {
            gunText.text = gun.ToString();
        }
        int k = 1;
        while(Input.touchCount > k)
        {
            Vector2 deltaposition = Vector2.zero;
            if(Input.GetTouch(k).position.x > Screen.width / 2 - 100)
            {
                if(k == 0)
                    deltaposition = Input.GetTouch(k).deltaPosition;
                deltaposition.x /= Screen.dpi;
                if(deltaposition.x != 0)
                {
                    float speedX = 3 * deltaposition.x;
                    player.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * speedX);
                }
            }
            k++;
        }


        CharacterMove();
        GameGravity();
    }
```

Jostic code

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
public class MobileController: MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerDownHandler
{
    private Image jostickBG;
    [SerializeField]
    private Image jostick;
    public Vector2 inputVector;
    private void Start()
    {
        jostickBG = GetComponent<Image>();
        jostick = transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>();
    }

    public virtual void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData ped)
    {

    }
    public virtual void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData ped)
    {
        inputVector = Vector2.zero;
        jostick.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = Vector2.zero;
    }

    public virtual void OnDrag(PointerEventData ped)
    {
        Vector2 pos;
        if(RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(jostickBG.rectTransform, ped.position, ped.pressEventCamera, out pos))
        {
            pos.x = (pos.x / jostickBG.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x);
            pos.y = (pos.y / jostickBG.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y);
            inputVector = new Vector2(pos.x * 2 - 0, pos.y * 2 - 0);
            inputVector = (inputVector.magnitude > 1.0f) ? inputVector.normalized : inputVector;
            jostick.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(inputVector.x * (jostickBG.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x / 2), inputVector.y * (jostickBG.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y / 2));
        }
    }

    public float Horizontal()
    {
        return inputVector.x;
    }

    public float Vertical()
    {
        return inputVector.y;
    }
}
```

Comment: We need more code. Are they in same script ? How k is modified? How these methods are called? Are they in update?..so more code

Comment: yes, update method

Comment: ok but need more code..like i say

Comment: i edit code, please check

Comment: https://ibb.co/CmSZtmv this problem (2 touch)

Comment: how many simultaneaous touchount could you have? one for player, one for joy and more?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214035/discussion-between-frenchy-and--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is coming from the while loop:

your logic is only for k=0 on rotation player and k=1 for joy, and you begin to enter in the while loop  with the value k=1, the test if is always false if for this value its the position of rotation player

```
if(Input.GetTouch(k).position.x > Screen.width / 2 - 100)
```

i suggest you to refactor your code like that:

when you have 2 touches k=0 and k=1, find the right action for each touches.

i dont understant why you dont enter in the while loop with k=0?